# HTML ul li width not correct

Tags: html, html-lists, anchor

I am trying to create a drop-down-menu and i am having some problems with the width of the links as they get out of the box...

check it out http://jsfiddle.net/V4Cgn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/V4Cgn/8/
add overflow:hidden; to #popupbox

Answer (score 2):

Use exact width:

```
#popupbox ul li a{
    padding: 10px;
    width:129px;
    float:left;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use an exact width you can do this with percentages still. You're padding was wrong.

```
#popupbox ul li{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
#popupbox ul li a{
    width:90%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10%;
    float:left;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I've set an example up here - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/TnZZj/4/

If you can use an exact with though I'd do that instead.